# Ubuntu 22.04 - Wifi showing but not working

Tags: networking, drivers, nvidia, network-manager, vpn

I am on Ubuntu 22.04 and always had some annoying connection issue but has been able to get them fix with `sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager` but since last update of NVidia Driver to nvidia-driver535 (proprietary, tested) it show that my WIFI is connected, but I am unable to use the browser, update, download package, nothing is working anymore.

In setting - WIFI it says that I am connected and the signal strength is Excellent

When I do:

```
    nmcli

    wlp0s20f3: 
    connected to HomeSweetHome
    "Intel Comet Lake PCH CNVi"
    wifi (iwlwifi), 34:2E:B7:1A:E5:55, hw, mtu 1500
    ip4 default
    inet4 192.168.1.78/24
    route4 192.168.1.0/24 metric 600
    route4 169.254.0.0/16 metric 1000
    route4 default via 192.168.1.254 metric 600
    inet6 fe80::2cbd:62c5:1e7a:9812/64
    route6 fe80::/64 metric 1024

    p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3: disconnected
    "p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3"
    wifi-p2p, hw

    lo: unmanaged
    "lo"
    loopback (unknown), 00:00:00:00:00:00, sw, mtu 65536

    DNS configuration:
    servers: 192.168.1.254 75.153.171.124
    interface: wlp0s20f3
```

I am on
Manufacturer: LENOVO
Product Name: 82AE
Version: IdeaPad Slim 7 15IMH05

I have Private Access Internet VPN install. I deactivated it, reboot many time and NO changes. Still no internet.

I did try so many things that I am about to flush everything down. A new install seems to be the only way to maybe fix this but I am tired of having to re-install everything and all the package that I use (Would be the 3rd time since I switch from Mint to Ubuntu)...

I wrote this post from my Work computer.

Thank you